# Signal sending to PGRP

Tags: c, signals, ipc

Is there a way to send a signal to all the processes of a process ID group except for the one that is sending it?

With `kill(0, SIGUSR1)` we can send it to all the processes of a group including the one calling it, but what if we wanted to send it to all except for the one calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
...
signal(SIGUSR1, SIG_IGN); /* Ignore own signal */

killpg(getpgrp(), SIGUSR1); /* Send SIGUSR1 to pgrp */
```